# charts not shifting to the left when deleting columns through VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to delete columns A:Y and so the data to the right gets shifted left to column A to the end column, However, the chart included it not shifting to the left properly but the data does.

Some charts moved properly in the first worksheets. The rest got retained in its original column location.

I tried `Range("A:Y").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft`, `Columns("A:Y").Delete`, `EntireColumns delete` etc.

[image]

```
Sub PasteAsValuesDeleteColumns()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

'    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
'            ws.Range("A:Y").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
'            Application.CutCopyMode = False
'    Next ws

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            ws.Activate
            ws.Range("A:Y").Delete
    Next ws

'    By codename
'    KSheet01.Activate
'    Range("A:Y").Delete
'
'    KSheet02.Activate
'    Range("A:Y").Delete
'
'    KSheet03.Activate
'    Range("A:Y").Delete

    MsgBox "done"

End Sub
```

Comment: Note that they are shifting to the left properly when doing it manually and not via VBA

Comment: In the **Format Chart Area** pane, select **Properties**, and then select the appropriate option: "Move but don't size with cells" or "Move and size with cells". Checkout https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/move-or-resize-a-chart-f9d6087b-1d7b-4a72-8d81-1d0788ea783f (last section *"Prevent a chart from moving and sizing with cells on the worksheet"*)

Answer (score 1):

In your chart's Properties, you have selected the `Dont move or size with cells` option. Change it to `Move and size with cells` or `Move but don't size with cells` manually or programmatically by:

```
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("YOUR CHART NAME").Activate
    Selection.Placement = xlMoveAndSize 'Move and size with cells
    'or Selection.Placement = xlMove to move but not size with cells
```